# Dynamically retrieve firebase database text and add text data to a cardview

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-cardview

I want to create an app for leaving comments. For that, I create three pages for my app
The first page is a home activity for refresh and retrieves comment data.
The second page is for upload the name, email, title, comment of a commenter.
The third page is for viewing the name, title, email of a corresponding comment post which is the clicked post from home activity.
On the second page save title, email, name, comment to the firebase database. After that, I want to retrieve all comments on the first page with refresh layout and add it into each and separate card view from the firebase database for every refresh of a layout. And set each unique OnClickListener for all comments.

(Sorry for 500 lines of codes.)

Edit :

I have solve this problem using firebase database.

First upload data using firebase database upload next by next add push() method.

And retrieve data using addValueEventListener()

Add recycler view in home activity and add xml for posts
Add linear layout manager.
And using inflate method to inflate posts.xml in home activity.
Retrive text and add to posts.xml.

Binding data ( click to open seperate posts) using adapter
And add put extra method to add post text to binding data activity.

You can add card view in posts.xml not in home activity.

Help me how to do that.

Comment: Can you please add some code, so we can start giving you suggestions?

Comment: Ok I will add some code of my project.

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **500 (five hundred)** lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Comment: Sorry for the 500 lines of code. Check edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to use a recycler view.

The recycler view will have an item row with the cardview (and some text views on the card)

2. In the view holder of the recycler view, set an onclick listener to the card. This will be like setting a listener for all the cards.
3. Getting data:

Use firebase listeners and update recycler adapter data when the fire base collection changes.

Comment: what is a diseases listener, can you please add tips for making my app

Comment: Firebase listener. Read on fetching data from firebase. Once the listener is triggered,, check if data exists, and update the data for the recycler view

Comment: Thanks for your answer